# How do I setup a different wallet account to Google play store?

Tags: google-play, android-pay

I registered as a developer to the play store using some account. Example: android@a.com

The finance stuff is done on another account: finance@a.com

**How can I use the finance wallet account with the android's google play account?**

Comment: I don't mind, but SO community may - this is a question that you should send to Google support directly, [not here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I agree that I can contact Google support, which I have. BUT, there may be someone who knows how to do it. If such a person exists, I'd love to get his answer on StackExchange.

Comment: I asked in the meta site where's the the right place to put such a question and the only answer I got was SO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211760/where-do-i-post-a-question-on-issues-creating-google-wallet-merchant-account

Comment: Does [this Android Developer Help item](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2528691?hl=en) help?